# Could we have a briefer :info output in ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is there a reason why the output of `:info` in ghci is listing the type name after every class it belongs to? For example

```
Prelude> :info Int`
```

prints

```
...
instance Bounded Int -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Enum Int -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Eq Int -- Defined in `GHC.Classes*emphasized text*'
...
```

What I'd prefer to read is something like:

```
Prelude> :info Int
...
instance Bounded -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Enum -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Eq -- Defined in `GHC.Classes*emphasized text*'
...
```

or even better would be brief notation like

```
Prelude> :info Int
...
instance of Bounded, Enum, Eq,...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe, a reason would be parameterised types. To illustrate my point, look at this example :

```
$ ghci -XMultiParamTypeClasses -XFlexibleInstances
-- ...
Prelude> class Klass a b c where {f :: a b c -> c}
Prelude> data Typ b c = Typ b c
Prelude> instance Klass Typ b Integer where { f (Typ _ c) = c + 1 }
Prelude> let x = Typ "a" 3
Prelude> f x
4
Prelude> :info Typ
data Typ b c = Typ b c  -- Defined at <interactive>:3:6
instance Klass Typ b Integer -- Defined at <interactive>:4:10
```